# SPServices GetListItems to parent site in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, jquery, spservices

I'm trying to use spservices getlistitems to read a list on the root site. This is to populate the navigation for a custom master page so the navigation list just exists on the root site : i.e. `http://mysp.sharepoint.com/`

I'm able to call the list successfully from the root site, but if I go to a subsite (`mysp.sharepoint.com/dept/hr` ) the call does not work.

I tried specifying with the webUrl but it did not work either:

```
$().SPServices({
   webUrl: "https://mysp.sharepoint.com",
   operation: "GetListItems",
   async: false,
   listName: "navigation",
   CAMLViewFields: caml,  
   completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
     $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
              var title = $(this).attr('ows_Title');

    });
   }
});
```

Any ideas on how I can call the list in a parent site?

Comment: For querying the root (http://mysp.sharepoint.com/) you can simply pass '/' as webUrl, or use _spPageContextInfo. Check you console error logs for that particular call. It could be due the permission

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace the **webUrl** with **webURL** in *line 2*. It will work fine. Refer the updated code below.

```
$().SPServices({
 webURL: "https://mysp.sharepoint.com",
 operation: "GetListItems",
 async: false,
 listName: "navigation",
 CAMLViewFields: caml,  
 completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
 $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
          var title = $(this).attr('ows_Title');

 });
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I passed in the list GUID and it worked - an explicit url or '/' for the webUrl property did not work.

```
$().SPServices({
  //    webUrl: "https://mysp.sharepoint.com",   //did not work
    operation: "GetListItems",
    async: false,
    listName: "{300cdf29-6f57-424c-99b2-8fad22453fge}",
    CAMLViewFields: caml,   
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
     $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
              var title = $(this).attr('ows_Title');

     });
   }
 });
```

Comment: Put the updated code..